# workflow - send notification everyday until status = complete

Tags: workflow

Is there a way to send daily notification if the status column is not Complete? If yes, how? I tried several ways like parallel workflow, etc. but can't get this to work. I declared a variable call daysremaining and i dont know to run the same workflow everyday and send reminder notification. Using SharePoint 2010 enterprise.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Updated my question with sharepoint 2010 ent version.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with 2010. If you are using 2013 based workflow, then you can pause until 24 hours and loop it, so that it runs everyday

Comment: if the underlying component is a task, you can send over due reminders everyday until the task is complete ootb.

Answer (score 0):

Workflows are triggered while creating or updating an item or they can be run manually.

With SharePoint 2010 you have the option to

1. Write a timer job to send out the email or start the workflow every day.
2. Write a console application to run the workflow or send out the email and
   deploy it as a Windows Scheduled task.